# Any disadvantages with using a sort key with low cardinality?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For my table, I have the attributes:

1. ItemId
2. ProductName

Only ItemId + ProductName is unique. However ItemId has very high cardinality and is virtually unique, just not guaranteed. ProductName has very low cardinality (~5 different values).
Client will always pass in ItemId + ProductName to get the item.

Approach 1
Originally I was thinking of setting (simple) primary key's partition key to ItemId + ProductName (string concat).

Approach 2
However, since primary key cannot be changed after table is created, I'm thinking of keeping the sort key as a placeholder. So setting (composite) primary key's partition key to ItemId and sort key to ProductName.

The benefit is in case I want to add things to the sort key in the future (like version number), I can do it without migrating table. Though right now I don't see what I would add.

But are there any downsides (such as performance) with Approach 2 as-is (sort key being low cardinality), compared to Approach 1?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using on-demand pricing, then this should have no effect on price/performance.

If not, then there can be - in general - some differences: https://blog.yugabyte.com/11-things-you-wish-you-knew-before-starting-with-dynamodb/

> Over-provisioning to handle hot partitions.
>
> In DynamoDB, the total provisioned IOPS is evenly divided across all
> the partitions. Therefore, it is extremely important to choose a
> partition key that will evenly distribute reads and writes across
> these partitions. If a table ends up having a few hot partitions that
> need more IOPS, total throughput provisioned has to be high enough so
> that ALL partitions are provisioned with the throughput needed at the
> hottest partition. This can lead to dramatic cost increases and
> frustrated engineers.

In your particular case it should not have any effect either.

Comment: Thanks, great link. I forgot to mention but I've added to question, ItemId has very high cardinality, practically unique, just not guaranteed. Does that change anything with my approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without knowing how much volume you expect...

Generally, you want a partition key with high cardinality.  The sort key cardinality generally doesn't matter.

However, if you anticipate a small number of the itemId getting the most traffic, then you might run into issues with "hot partitions"; although the risk is [greatly reduced now-a-days](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/).

Furthermore, hot partitions are only a problem if you DDB table ends up partitioned in the first place.  DDB partitions your data when storage gets above 10GB* or when RCU/WCU required is more than 3000/1000 respectively.

*10GB isn't even guaranteed, a DDB table w/o local secondary indexes can have a partition larger than 10GB.